# IE8 adds slash to html5 elements

Tags: html, dom, internet-explorer-8

I tried doing the document.createElement("header"); but in my DOM I get this:

```
<header/>
    <h1>Test Page</h1>
</header/>
```

Instead of:

```
<header>
    <h1>Test Page</h1>
</header>
```

Can anybody please make any suggestions?
Thanks,
Brad

Answer (score 1):

IE 8 does not know about html5 so you have to use some tricks when you want to use it:

```
<!-- ENABLE HTML5 FOR DUMB BROWSER --> 
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the [innershiv](http://jdbartlett.github.com/innershiv/).